# List manipulation Python

Tags: python, sql

I have 2 lists:

```
name_info = ['0.abc','450.xyz','7.garfunkl','Coma','Cancer']  
XY_coorinfo = ['1234:5678', '2345:6543','3245:1234', '4587:2346', '6785:23987']
```

Output I want :

```
0,abc,1234,5678
450,xyz,2345,6543
7,garfunkl,3245,1234
,Coma,4587,2346
,Cancer,6785,23987
```

I think I need list manipulation but not sure how to match 1:1 on two lists? I tried an `IF` clause inside the `name_id` and it works but I want an else clause to say if it doesn't find the `"."` make it empty?

```
def name_table(cur_ic,table_names, column_name,print_out=False ):
    #print (table_names)
    id = []
    name_info = []
    name_info = cur_ic.execute("SELECT nameandid FROM one_table ; " ).fetchall()
    XY_Coordinfo = []
    XY_Coordinfo = cur_ic.execute('''SELECT coor_rot FROM another_table WHERE id < '431'; ''').fetchall()
    return name_info, XY_Coordinfo



def write_outfile(cur_ic, name_info, XY_coordinfo,print_out=True):
    #print name_info, XY_Coordinfo  

    name_id = [x.split('.', 1)[0] for x in partitioninfo if '.' in x ]


if __name__ =='__main__':
    sqlite_db = "sample.sqLiteDB"
    conn_ic,cur_ic = connect(sqlite_db)
    all_db_fetch(cur_ic, print_out=False) 
    table_names,column_name = all_db_fetch(cur_ic)
    name_table(cur_ic,table_names,column_name, print_out=False)     
    name_info,XY_Coordinfo = info_table(cur_ic,table_names,column_name)
    write_outfile(cur_ic, name_info, XY_coordinfo,print_out=True)
```

Comment: I think we can ignore the  first def module . And just use the two lists as example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to produce exactly your output:

```
name_info_split = [e.split('.') if (len(e.split('.')) == 2) else ['', e] for e in name_info]
XY_coorinfo_split = [e.split(':') for e in XY_coorinfo]
for i in range(len(name_info_split)):
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(name_info_split[i][0], name_info_split[i][1], XY_coorinfo_split[i][0], XY_coorinfo_split[i][1]))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip()` to iterate over two lists simultaneously and `split` and `join` to the required format:

```
name_info = ['0.abc','450.xyz','7.garfunkl','Coma','Cancer'] 
XY_coorinfo = ['1234:5678', '2345:6543','3245:1234', '4587:2346', '6785:23987']

for x, y in zip(name_info, XY_coorinfo):
    print(','.join(x.split('.') + y.split(':')))

# 0,abc,1234,5678
# 450,xyz,2345,6543                                           
# 7,garfunkl,3245,1234                                        
# Coma,4587,2346                                              
# Cancer,6785,23987
```

For the exact output:

```
name_info = ['0.abc','450.xyz','7.garfunkl','Coma','Cancer'] 
XY_coorinfo = ['1234:5678', '2345:6543','3245:1234', '4587:2346', '6785:23987']

for x, y in zip(name_info, XY_coorinfo):
    l, _ , r = x.partition('.')
    if not r:
        l = f',{l}'
        print(','.join([l] + y.split(':')))
    else:
        print(','.join([l, r] + y.split(':')))

# 0,abc,1234,5678
# 450,xyz,2345,6543
# 7,garfunkl,3245,1234
# ,Coma,4587,2346
# ,Cancer,6785,23987
```

Comment: output doesn't match

Comment: This worked for joining them. But yes output needs empty character if it doesnt find the split. That should be an easy fix I guess.. I will dig around.

Comment: @Ram, sorry for the confusion. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this might be:

```
# split up the first list into elements
n = []
for i in name_info:
   n.append(i.split('.'))
# split up the second list into elements
m = []
for j in XY_coordinfo:
   m.append(j.split(':'))
# now create your final list
x = []
for k in range(len(n)) # here we assume they are the same length
   x.append(n[k] + m[k])
```

This results in x where of:

```
[['0', 'abc', '1234', '5678'],
 ['450', 'xyz', '2345', '6543'],
 ['7', 'garfunkl', '3245', '1234'],
 ['Coma', '4587', '2346'],
 ['Cancer', '6785', '23987']]
```

If you need to combine this for printable form you can do that with:

```
for l in x:
   print(','.join(l))
```

resulting with:

```
""""
0,abc,1234,5678
450,xyz,2345,6543
7,garfunkl,3245,1234
Coma,4587,2346
Cancer,6785,23987
"""
```

Done!

Comment: you can do everying togther in a single loop. but it is good solution for someone new

Answer (score 0):

```
name_info = ['0.abc','450.xyz','7.garfunkl','Coma','Cancer']
XY_coorinfo = ['1234:5678', '2345:6543','3245:1234', '4587:2346', '6785:23987']

for i,j in zip(name_info,XY_coorinfo):

    io = (i[:i.index('.')],i[i.index('.')+1:]) if '.' in i else ('',i)
    print(*io,*j.split(':'),sep=',')


    """
    output

    0,abc,1234,5678
    450,xyz,2345,6543
    7,garfunkl,3245,1234
    ,Coma,4587,2346
    ,Cancer,6785,23987

    """
```